# How to set gap/space between columns?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I am trying to set space between each column in the chart, using WPF charting toolkit.
How can I display or which property is there to set the space between the columns according to the image given below:

Thank you in advance.

[[image: Chart[1]]

Comment: Have you tried reading WPF's documentation yet?

Comment: yes, but I can only set single value to it.not the range.

Comment: Range can also be viewed as a single value.

Comment: I incorporated code from a comment and improved minor formatting.

Comment: Change the `Width` of your `ColumnDataPoint`.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. i changed property of ColumnDataPoint's MaxWidth to desired value.